# Show that $L^2$-norm of function and its Fourier transform coincide

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $D\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ be bounded. Moreover, let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $$\hat f(\omega):=\int e^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle\omega,\;\cdot\;\rangle}f\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}\;\;\;\text{for }\omega\in\mathbb R^d$$ for $f\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda^{\otimes d};\mathbb C)$.

In equation (10) on [p. 6 of this paper](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w%7Eraananf/projects/kdm/paper.pdf#page=6), I've read that $$\int_D|f|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{[-\pi,\:\pi]^d}|\hat f|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}\tag1.$$ I guess it is assumed hat $f\in\mathcal L^2(\lambda^{\otimes d})$. The author claims that $(1)$ follows from Parseval's identity.

> How do we show $(1)$?

Okay, since $D$ is bounded, there is a $r>0$ with $$D\subseteq\left[-\frac r2,\frac r2\right]\tag2.$$ Now, we know that $$e_k:=\frac1{r^{\frac d2}}e^{{\rm i}\frac{2\pi}r\langle k,\;\cdot\;\rangle}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb Z^d$$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2\left(\left[-\frac r2,\frac r2\right]\right)$. Let $$\tilde f(x):=\left.\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{, if }x\in D;\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in D.$$ By Parseval's identity, $$\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(D)}^2=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d}\left|\left\langle\tilde f,e_k\right\rangle_{L^2\left(\left[-\frac r2,\frac r2\right]\right)}\right|^2\tag3.$$ We clearly have $$\hat f(k)=\frac1{r^d}\int e^{-{\rm i}\frac{2\pi}r\langle k,\:x\rangle}f\left(\frac xr\right)\:\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}x)\tag4$$ for all $k\in\mathbb R^d$.

However, I still can't conclude $(1)$ ...

*Remark*: If I remember correctly, there is a result of the form $(1)$ for functions $f$ belonging to the Schwarz space ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Folland - Real Analysis, Plancherel theorem proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936502/folland-real-analysis-plancherel-theorem-proof)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the reference. What I still don't get is the normalization $frac1{2\pi}$ (which definition of the Fourier transform is being used?) and the restriction to $[-\pi,\pi]^d$ (does the Fourier transform vanish outside $[-\pi,\pi]^d$?).

Comment: I believe (but I am not sure) that [their normalization $\frac1{2\pi}$](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_de_Fourier#Extension_de_la_transformation_de_L1%E2%88%A9L2_%C3%A0_L2)  corresponds to [the following definition:](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_de_Fourier#D%C3%A9finition) $\hat f(\xi)\ = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\, \mathrm e^{-{\rm i}\xi x}\,\mathrm dx.$ As for your 2nd question, I cannot find any other explanation as yours, which should be an hypothesis but scrutinizing your paper I could find it nowhere. Sorry, I reach my threshold of incompetence.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your comment. But your definition does not involve a normalization factor. So, I still don't get where it comes from.

Comment: The factor is not inside the definition but pops up in the [proof of Plancherel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_de_Fourier#Extension_de_la_transformation_de_L1%E2%88%A9L2_%C3%A0_L2), I think.

Comment: @AnneBauval Hm ... So you agree that the factor shold not pop up if we use the definition of the Fourier transform that I gave here, right? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem.

Comment: @AnneBauval Different conventions would answer my first question, but the second question regarding the restriction to $[-\pi,\pi]^d$ is even more mysterious to me.

Comment: 1) Yes, I agree. 2) Mysterious to me as well. Sorry, I am not able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is obviously not true for all Schwartz functions and all bounded Borel sets $D\subset\Bbb{R}^d$, let alone all $L^2$  functions. Suppose $f$ is a Gaussian, then $\hat{f}$ is again a Gaussian (if I remember correctly, with this convention, $f(x)=e^{-\pi|x|^2}$ implies $\hat{f}=f$), so you cannot have different integration regions on both sides. Even if we don’t know about Gaussians (weird, but ok), we can still see (1) is wrong in general, because the LHS of the equation depends on the domain $D$, while the RHS doesn’t. Hence, we have by the monotone convergence theorem, and Plancherel’s theorem that
\begin{align}
\|\hat{f}\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^d)}^2&=\|f\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^d)}^2=\sup\limits_{\text{bounded $D\subset\Bbb{R}^d$}}\int_{D}|f|^2\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]^d}|\hat{f}|^2\,d\omega.
\end{align}
With this convention, I don’t think the $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ should be there, but even if we disregard that, then this equation implies $\int_{\Bbb{R}^d\setminus[-\pi,\pi]^d}|\hat{f}|^2\,d\omega=0$, i.e for every Schwartz function $f$, the Fourier transform is compactly supported in $[-\pi,\pi]^d$. This is obviously wrong, since you know the Fourier transform is an isomorphism on Schwartz space (and on $L^2$). If we don’t want to invoke such “abstract” results, we know that Fourier transform converts dilations to modulations and vice-versa, so doing this appropriately, we can easily construct Fourier transforms with arbitrarily large supports (provided of course we know that the Fourier-transform is not identically zero).

So, if you want $(1)$ to be true, you need to make assumptions on the supports of the functions involved.

Comment: You remember correctly, your formula for $\hat f$ for the Gaussian $f$ is correct.

Comment: Did you take a look at the paper? I don't see any assumption which implies that we can restrict to $[-\pi,\pi]^d$. I guess some kind of "band-limited" assumption is made.

Comment: @0xbadf00d i glossed over it, but it looked too weird, and out of my wheelhouse, so I just made this remark. Anyway, I don’t think there’s a simpler characterization for this set of functions, other than just saying $f$ is such that $\hat{f}$ is supported in $[-\pi,\pi]^d$. This, like you said, is an assumption on the type of frequencies that are admissible.

Comment: Thank you for your effort!

Comment: One last thing: Shouldn't the correct formula be $$\int_D|f|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}=\int|\hat g|^2\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}\tag5,$$ where $g$ is the extension of $f$ by $0$ outside $D$? I don't think that we can restrict the domain of integration on the right-hand side in general.

Comment: @0xbadf00d sure